# How does a WiFi device communicate with router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

When I enable WiFi on a computer or on my phone, does it send radio waves back to the router in case of say, uploading something or, is it that router always sending them to PC? If my PC sends back then how can I check if the frequency like if its 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz compared to router's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device and router will communicate back and fourth constantly with radio waves, even if you are browsing and downloading, your device still has to send requests and other background data for your router to process in the same way that the router sends the downloaded data to your device.

Typically is you have a dual band router than then the different connections for 5GHz and 2.4Ghz will have different names and will appear as separate connections in your network manager, if not you may have to open your routers settings and manually enable the 5GHz band or change the names so that you can differentiate between them.